# Significant numbers of $2900 \pm 100$ is 2. How to generalize derivation of significant figures?

Tags: significant-figures, rounding-unit

Question from stackexchange
[Significant figures with a plus-minus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167657/significant-figures-with-a-plus-minus)
$2900 \pm 100$

I would calculate:
100 -> #1 minimum sigfig
and then increase that with 1, because otherwise 29 will not fit
-> #1 + #1 = #2.

But is the answer given as
$\log_{10}(\frac{2900}{2\cdot 100}) \approx 1.16$

also correct and meaningfull? And why?

Comment: Follow the answer in your link to the conclusion given.  Essentially, any digit for which some limits on its value can be specified which are narrower than "all the possible values" is a significant digit.  More directly, the $0.16$ portion of a digit represents the greater-than-zero significance of that digit.

Comment: How many significant figures in $2900 \pm 9900$?

Comment: @abiessu: I get the idea. But why not simply $\log_{10}(\frac{2900}{100})$. The true value is in 2800..3000. And the distance between true value and given value is at most 100. So we just need to ensure that 2900 is at least in the precision of 100. Precision in this context is the number of sig figs. It is like "how many multiples of 100 is 2900" and from that sig fig determination can be get.

Comment: @DavidK: I guess it is 2, because 9900 has 2 sig figs. And 2900 is not bigger than 9900. 9900 has 2 sig figs due to the rule that trailing zeros don't count, if there is no decimal point.

Comment: In $2900\pm 9900$ there would be $1$ significant digit, being the leading digit of $10000$.  We can only say that this leading digit has value in $\{0,1\}$ while none of the other digits are limited in any way.

Comment: I'm not convinced $2900 \pm 9900$ has even **one** significant figure. After all, we don't even know whether the value is positive or negative. The value could even be zero.

Comment: @davidk But separate from all of that, we do know that $2900\pm 9900$ is limited in value and the limits of the possible values it could take on can be ascribed to the $10000$'s place, therefore this digit has significance in helping us pin down the value.  If we were to add another number with precision $100000\pm 100$, the result of that addition would have a significant digit in the same location.

Comment: @abiessu What you've identified is the maximum _order of magnitude_ of $2900\pm 9900$, which is about $10^5.$ But the range of values is $-7000$ to $12800,$ so the leading digit could be anything. Interestingly, the $\log_{10}$ formula in the question gives $\log_{10}(2900/19800) \approx -0.834,$ that is, less than zero significant digits. We could also consider $2900\pm7000,$ where the $10000$s digit is always $0$ but the $1000$s digit could be any digit. What I mean is that "significant figures" loses meaning when the uncertainty overwhelms the nominal value.

Comment: @davidk: that's fair.